# Erro ao colocar Virtualbox como serviço

Tags: virtualbox, services

Criei um serviço no windows pra para poder configurar minha VM no modo *Headless*, com o comando:

```
sc.exe create DailyLubuntu binpath= "\"C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxHeadless.exe\"  startvm Daily LUbuntu - Lucas" DisplayName= \"Daily Lubuntu VM" start= "auto"
```

O serviço foi criado com êxito, porem quando vou inicializar o serviço com o comando:

```
> net start DailyLubuntu
```

, aparece este erro:

> Erro de sistema 2. O sistema não pode encontrar o arquivo especificado. Para obter mais ajuda, digite NET HELPMSG 2186.

Comment: Se você tentar iniciar a VM pelo VirtualBox, funciona?

Comment: Quando inicializo pelo VirtualBox ela funciona

Comment: Só para te avisar. Neste momento há 3 votos para fechar a sua pergunta como fora do escopo por não ser sobre programação (mas nenhum destes votos é meu). Eu pessoalmente, não saberia dizer se o fechamento por este motivo é válido ou não.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Existe um projeto chamado VBoxVmService que faz esse serviço por você](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vboxvmservice/). Basta instalar, alterar o arquivo `VBoxVmService.ini` dentro de `C:\vms` e reiniciar o serviço.